# How to change the color of a gnome-terminal profile including the prompt?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have created 2 profiles for gnome-terminal.  One is meant to be green-on-black, the other is meant to be red-on-black.  They do change some of the terminal colors, but my prompts remain bright bold green.  Is there a way to force the prompt to use the profile colors?

FWIW, I'm using Xubuntu 16.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops,

Just seen the prompt color is hard-coded in ~/.bashrc.  How embarrassing.

I changed the prompt from this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

to this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1m\]\u@\h:\w\$ \[\033[0m\]'
```

And that did the trick.

Comment: Actually, that code has issues w/ line-wrapping.  An easier way to do it would be `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[$(tput bold)\]\u@\h:\w\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]'`

Comment: I fixed it for you